# Using lodash to transform data into object properties instead of a collection

Tags: javascript, lodash

following up on my previous question about transforming data using lodash, this time i require output to be an object properties instead of being a collection. I appreciate the help and if someone can also guide me where to begin properly so i have a better understanding of these concepts

**Sample Data**

```
var sample = [{
    "changeType": 1,
    "type": "changeAccount",
    "updated": {
      "id": 71,
      "company": 124201,
      "user": 8622
    }
  },
  {
    "changeType": 2,
    "type": "changeAccount",
    "updated": {
      "id": 70,
      "company": 124201,
      "user": 8622
    }
  },
  {
    "changeType": 1,
    "type": "changeproduct",
    "updated": {
      "id": 15,
      "company": 124201,
      "user": 8622
    }
  }
]

// what I tried
var result = _.mapValues(_.groupBy(sample, "type"), x => x.map(y => _.omit(y, "changeType")));

console.log(result);
```

**Expected Result**

```
var output = {
    "ChangeAccount": {

        "changeTypes":
            {
                "add": [{}], //type 1

                "remove": [{}] //type 2


            }
    },

    "ChangeProduct":{

        "changeTypes":
            {
                "add": [{}], //type 1

                "remove": [{}] //type 2  will be empty in this case
            }
    }
}
```

**Previous Question Answer**

```
const fn = arr =>
  map(groupBy(arr, 'type'), (group, type) => ({ // group and map to array of objects
    type,
    ...mapValues( // spread after mapping the values to extract updated
      groupBy(group, 'changeType'), // group again by changeType
      items => items.map(item => pick(item, 'updated') // extract the updated from each item
    ))
  }))
```

**Previous Answer Output **

```
 [
    {
        [
            {
                "updated": {
                    "id": 71,
                    "company": 124201,
                    "user": 8622
                }
            }
            ],
        [
            {
                "updated": {
                    "id": 70,
                    "company": 124201,
                    "user": 8622
                }
            }
            ],
        "type": "changeAccount"
    },
        {
            [
                {
                    "updated": {
                        "id": 15,
                        "company": 124201,
                        "user": 8622
                    }
                }
                ],
            "type": "changeproduct"
        }
```

Comment: What have you tried on which you need help with?

Comment: Hi @Rikin i tried var result = _.mapValues(_.groupBy(sample, "type"), x => x.map(y => _.omit(y, "changeType"))); Expected Result is what i am trying to get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will say that you are not forced to use lodash, and that you can make this with just plain javascript. But, since you have required to use lodash, here is an easy way. You can simplify it depending on how hard your requirements are.

```
const omitChangeType = ({changeType, ...rest}) => rest // this is just ES6, don't need lodash for this

_.mapValues(
    _.groupBy(sample, "type"), 
    (x) => ({ 
        changeTypes: { 
            add: x.filter(_.matches({ changeType: 1 })).map(omitChangeType), 
            remove: x.filter(_.matches({ changeType: 2 })).map(omitChangeType)
        }})
    )
```

What I like about this solution is that you have an idea of how the final structure will look like.

Output:

```
{
  "changeAccount": {
    "changeTypes": {
      "add": [
        {
          "type": "changeAccount",
          "updated": {
            "id": 71,
            "company": 124201,
            "user": 8622
          }
        }
      ],
      "remove": [
        {
          "type": "changeAccount",
          "updated": {
            "id": 70,
            "company": 124201,
            "user": 8622
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "changeproduct": {
    "changeTypes": {
      "add": [
        {
          "type": "changeproduct",
          "updated": {
            "id": 15,
            "company": 124201,
            "user": 8622
          }
        }
      ],
      "remove": []
    }
  }
}
```

In my solution I'm using a bit of ES destructuring, which is a very handy feature if you are going to work with data modification like this. [Take a look at this if](https://codeburst.io/es6-destructuring-the-complete-guide-7f842d08b98f) you are not familiar with it.
Also, I'm not sure if your intention is to just omit changeType or if you want to extract the updated part of each object. If you want to just pick the updated property of each object, just change every appearance by the following function name, and add this function declaration:

```js
const pickUpdated = ({updated}) => updated
```

So instead of `.map(omitChangeType)` you do `.map(pickUpdated)`

In that case the output will look like

```
{
  "changeAccount": {
    "changeTypes": {
      "add": [
        {
          "id": 71,
          "company": 124201,
          "user": 8622
        }
      ],
      "remove": [
        {
          "id": 70,
          "company": 124201,
          "user": 8622
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "changeproduct": {
    "changeTypes": {
      "add": [
        {
          "id": 15,
          "company": 124201,
          "user": 8622
        }
      ],
      "remove": []
    }
  }
}
```

Feel free to comment if you have any doubt

Comment: Thank you, can you explain what this does const `omitChangeType = ({changeType, ...rest}) => rest` // this is just ES6, don't need lodash for this

Comment: I recommend you to check the link I posted. That function does what the name says, it creates a copy of the object you pass in but it omits the changeType property. The syntax means: get the change property and copy the rest of the properties to a new object that we are calling rest in this case which is what we are returning

Comment: One question if i want to omit "user" property from this output, what is the best way

Answer (score 1):

try the solution, I know it looks bit messy. there are few thing to improve, but you will get an idea.

```
const result = sample.reduce((acc, obj)=> {
  let addOrRemove  = obj.changeType === 1 ? 'add' : 'remove';
  if(acc[obj.type] && acc[obj.type].changeTypes &&  acc[obj.type].changeTypes[addOrRemove]) {    
    acc[obj.type].changeTypes[addOrRemove].push({updated: obj.updated})
  } else  {
    acc[obj.type] = acc[obj.type] ? { ...acc[obj.type]}:{changeTypes: {}};
    acc[obj.type].changeTypes[addOrRemove] = [{updated :obj.updated}];
  }
  return acc;
}, {})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `_.groupBy()` and then use `_.mapValues()` to transform the groups (use `generateChangeTypes`). `generateChangeTypes` - In the groups use `_.groupBy()` and convert the type number to add/remove (using `changeTypes` object), and then use `_.mapValues()` with `_.map()` to extract he updated object.

### Version 1 - pipeline using `_.flow()`

```js
const { flow, partialRight: pr, groupBy, mapValues, map, } = _

const changeTypes = { 1: 'add', 2: 'remove' }

const generateChangeTypes = flow(
  pr(groupBy, o => changeTypes[o.changeType]), // group by changeType
  pr(mapValues, g => map(g, 'updated')) // extract the updated
)

const transform = flow(
  pr(groupBy, 'type'),
  pr(mapValues, group => ({
    changeTypes: {
      add: [], // default
      remove: [], // default
      ...generateChangeTypes(group)
    }
  }))
)

const sample = [{"changeType":1,"type":"changeAccount","updated":{"id":71,"company":124201,"user":8622}},{"changeType":2,"type":"changeAccount","updated":{"id":70,"company":124201,"user":8622}},{"changeType":1,"type":"changeproduct","updated":{"id":15,"company":124201,"user":8622}}]

const result = transform(sample)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

### Version 2 - using lodash chaining

```js
const sample = [{"changeType":1,"type":"changeAccount","updated":{"id":71,"company":124201,"user":8622}},{"changeType":2,"type":"changeAccount","updated":{"id":70,"company":124201,"user":8622}},{"changeType":1,"type":"changeproduct","updated":{"id":15,"company":124201,"user":8622}}]

const changeTypes = { 1: 'add', 2: 'remove' }

const result = _(sample)
  .groupBy('type')
  .mapValues(group => ({
    changeTypes: {
      add: [], // default
      remove: [], // default
      ..._(group)
      .groupBy(o => changeTypes[o.changeType]) // group by changeType text
      .mapValues(g => _.map(g, 'updated')) // extract the updated
      .value()
    }
  }))
  .value()

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

### Version 3 - lodash/fp with `_.flow()`

```js
const { flow, groupBy, mapValues, map, } = _

const changeTypes = { 1: 'add', 2: 'remove' }

const generateChangeTypes = flow(
  groupBy(o => changeTypes[o.changeType]), // group by changeType
  mapValues(map('updated')) // extract the updated
)

const transform = flow(
  groupBy('type'),
  mapValues(group => ({
    changeTypes: {
      add: [], // default
      remove: [], // default
      ...generateChangeTypes(group)
    }
  }))
)

const sample = [{"changeType":1,"type":"changeAccount","updated":{"id":71,"company":124201,"user":8622}},{"changeType":2,"type":"changeAccount","updated":{"id":70,"company":124201,"user":8622}},{"changeType":1,"type":"changeproduct","updated":{"id":15,"company":124201,"user":8622}}]

const result = transform(sample)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering this question as well :), Which one you think is the most efficient solution?

Comment: Welcome. They are identical. How many items do you have in your list?

Comment: There can be 500+ and is it possible to have `"ChangeAccount": {

        
            
                "add": [{}], //type 1

                "remove": [{}] //type 2


      
    },`